# EF does not generate correct SQL SELECT WHERE when using dynamic compiled predicate

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I am trying to create dynamic compiled predicate and use it for querying Entity Framework ObjectSet.
Following code is executed and correct result is returned,but SQL SELECT Statement is generated without WHERE clause:

```
 var db = new DBHelper();

 ParameterExpression entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty), "entity");
 var filterentity = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(entity, "HighSchoolID"), Expression.Constant(90, typeof(int))), entity);
 Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool> predicate = (Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool>)filterentity.Compile();

 var res = db.DBContext.Faculties.Where(predicate);
 dataGridView2.DataSource = res.ToList();
```

Generated SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[HighSchoolID] AS [HighSchoolID], 
    [Extent1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Faculties] AS [Extent1]
```

and when I use explicit expression like

```
var res = db.DBContext.Faculties.Where(f => f.HighSchoolID == 90);
```

correct SQL is generated.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[HighSchoolID] AS [HighSchoolID], 
    [Extent1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM [dbo].[Faculties] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 90 = [Extent1].[HighSchoolID]
```

How can i force EF to produce WHERE clause in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but could it be that you're setting `predicate` to a compiled `Func<...>` and not keeping it as an `Expression<Func<...>>`, so it's getting converted to IL before EF has a chance to process it? Have you tried e.g.

```
var predicate = 
   (Expression<Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool>>)filterentity;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Linq needs Expression of function, not a compiled function. Please use reflector to see what is generated by compiler for your linq expression.

Enire expression tree should be available to Linq where clause without compilation.

```
 var db = new DBHelper();

 ParameterExpression entity = 
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty), 
        "entity");

 Expression<Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool>> filterentity = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
      Expression.Property(entity, "HighSchoolID"), 
        Expression.Constant(90, typeof(int))), entity);

 // not at all needed...
 //Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool> predicate =
 //   (Func<HighSchoolServicesDataAccess.Faculty, bool>)filterentity.Compile();

 var res = db.DBContext.Faculties.Where(filterentity);
 dataGridView2.DataSource = res.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You created predicate but at the end you compiled it which means you it is not expression any more and once you pass it to the Where you are using linq-to-objects instead of linq-to-entities. It means that all records are transferred to the application and filtering is done in memory.

Try this instead:

```
var res=db.DBContext.Faculties.Where(filterentity);
dataGridView2.DataSource = res.ToList();
```

Comment: I do not agree, its bad to load everything and applying filtering in memory, this will still do exactly same. This will not generate different SQL, it will still generate same SQL.